# Using HashMap as Collection in Java

Tags: java, collections, jaxb, hashmap, guava

`JAXB` doesn't let you unmarshal already existing xml structures into `HashMap`s if they are not exactly the way `JAXB` expects them.

`JAXB` is fine with handling e.g. `LinkedList`s and filling them.

I was thinking of creating a interface with a `getKey()` method and a wrapper around the `HashMap` taking all objects that implement that interface. The wrapper can then use the `getKey()` method for all key related features of the map. The wrapper could then easily implement the `Collection` or `List` interface.

Because this idea doesn't seem to innovative to me I presume that it already exists in some package, but I'm not googling correctly for it... Can someone please name a good lib that can do this, or do I have to code this myself?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7793283/problems-marshalling-a-map-in-jaxb.  Regardless, the answer may be relevant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might consider extending `ForwardingList` of guava, and using a HashMap in the back. I don't know of any implementation that will leave you only the actual mapping.
Another alternative is creating JAXB `XmlAdapter` to adapt the values to your map. I think this one is more appropriate.

Comment: +1 for XmlAdapter.  Here is an example of how it can be done:  http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/07/xmladapter-jaxbs-secret-weapon.html

Comment: XmlApdater seems a bit too much. I think I will go with my own implementation of a Map with Collection interface

Comment: You can also Consider `ForwardingCollection`.

Answer (score 0):

If all you are trying to pass the information content of a `Map` as a `Collection`, use `Map.entrySet()`.  That gives you a `Set<Map.EntrySet<K,V>>` object; i.e. a collection whose elements are the key/value pairs of the `Map`.  To reconstruct a `Map` from the collection, you will need to iterate the set and perform an `put` for each element.

Comment: Thanks, no I want to add stuff to the map. But I don't want to save stuff in a list first to then copy it to a map, just because of JAXB